# Is there a method to print long arrays, in the range of hundred to thousand indices, to a txt file in GDB? (Debugging Fortran Code)

Tags: fortran, gdb

I am wondering whether it is possible to print the values of an array, specifying the format, to a .txt or other file while debugging a fortran program in gdb. This would be ideal if I could run this command when stopped at a breakpoint in the middle of my program. The reason I need this is because the arrays that I look at may have hundreds to several thousands of indices and analyzing them would be easier in a separate form after opening a text file. I don't have much C programming experience so I am having trouble outputting to a file using printf (I'm not exactly sure what the argument format is). I've tried searching through the internet to find this solution but the closest thing I have found is the dump command which isn't exactly what I'm looking for. I appreciate any help with this matter!

Comment: Why not write the necessary fortran code to write it all out to disk as needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to write a debug dump routine in your program, and call it from GDB with the `call` command.

The next simplest solution is to write a python routine to do the same. [Documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-API.html).